# google maps/places api - how to tell a company from particular subsidiary?

Tags: google-maps

i am trying to find a way to tell company from one subsidiary gotten from a map api.

For example, lets say there is a CompanyX in category 'hotels' and that it has 100 subsidiaries across the country. Next, i search for nearest 'hotels' to my currect location within some radius and i get one subsidiary of CompanyX (or in other words, one of their specific hotels). 
What i need is some consistent way to make relation from search reault hotel instance to CompanyX.

Fields in api results dont give me some clue on how to do it.

If anyone have some idea i would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: hi, well not quite. google doesnt seem to offer it out of the box but you have to be lucky company (or whoever provides the data) made some sense naming the entities. i was lucky in a way that i needed specific companies which all had some words in title + they were in specific categories ('hotels', for example) so i implicitly concluded its subsidiary. you could also check if they share same website or its hostname at least.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API web service to retrieve information from a variety of categories such as facility location, the main points of interest, geographic location. The  [place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place?hl=ko#status-codes) you can search for a text string adjacent to Donna. Place Search will return an overview of each place with the Places listing.

Add a place you can add the data of your application data from the Google Maps database. Then you can:
The data stored in the Google database can be updated immediately.
The transmission queue arbitration to add new locations to the Google Places database.

It can be differentiated from other apps with similar functionality.
You can create applications that target a specific user base or geographic location.
This can affect the results of executing the search place in my application.

Nearby request : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

You may  [bias](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing) results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This instructs the Place Auto-complete service to prefer showing results within that circle.